# VHDL unsigned vector vs integer comparison

Tags: compare, vhdl, unsigned

In vhdl, assume I have an unsigned vector defined as follows:

```
signal s_col_rd_check : unsigned(7 downto 0);
```

Now, whether I use the following library,

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Or the following

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

Can I use do a comparison between my unsigned vector and an integer value as follows?

```
some_assignment <= '1' when (s_col_rd_check < 190) else '0';
```

where 190 is just an integer.
Will the above comparison be the same whether I use either one of the libraries?

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Answer (score 10):

The `ieee.std_logic_arith` and `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` are proprietary Synopsys packages, and **not** defined as part of the IEEE VHDL standard.  So it is misleading that these packages use the `ieee` library name, since they are **not** defined as part of the IEEE standard.

A quick [Google search for "std_logic_arith.vhd"](https://www.google.com/#q=std_logic_arith.vhd+filetype:vhd) yielded at least three different versions of the package, so the answer to your question may depend on which version of the proprietary package your are using... which is a strong indication, that using these proprietary packages is not the right approach, if you want to have well-defined and identical behavior of the design across different tools.

So the reliable approach is to use only the `ieee.numeric_std`, which is part of the IEEE VHDL standard, thus having well-defined behavior.

And with `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`, you can do the comparison in:

```
some_assignment <= '1' when (s_col_rd_check < 190) else '0';
```

since `ieee.numeric_std` defines the function:

```
function "<" (L: UNSIGNED; R: NATURAL) return BOOLEAN;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see, and I agree with you 100%. But the problem is that I am stuck with using "std_logic_unsigned", and that is because I am working with an old design developed with someone else. And, I cannot change it to "numeric_std", and that is why I was wondering that using the function will be similar to the "numeric_std" one.

Comment: Since `ieee.std_logic_arith` is not standardized, I can't answer for the specific package `std_logic_arith` used in your design.  However, I have seen a case where `std_logic_arith` and `numeric_std` gives the exact same result for all argument values in the compare, so for the version of `std_logic_arith` I am using, the compare is equivalent.  Note that in the case of comparing `unsigned < natural`, the `std_logic_arith` applies, and not the `std_logic_unsigned`, since the latter is for comparing `std_logic_vector < natural` with `std_logic_vector` interpreted as unsigned.